# Reports won't run in batch

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

I am trying to run unmodified reports using batch processing in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009. I have set up my configuration, and set up an AOS printer to run the report on. When I send a report to the batch queue, it immediately has an error when it begins execution.

The error is as follows:

> Error executing code: SysGlobalCache object not initialized.
>
> (S)\Classes\SysGlobalCache\get (S)\Classes\ClassFactory\reportRunClass
>   - line 14 (S)\Classes\RunBaseReport\makeReportRun - line 19 (S)\Classes\RunBaseReport\unpack - line 31
>   (S)\Classes\RunbaseReportStd\unpack - line 26
>   (S)\Classes\BatchRun\runJobStatic - line 27

I have tried running three different reports: Customer, Vendor, and Purchase Lines. I get the same error every time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We faced a similar problem at my work, but didn't want to rely on having to set up the legacy batch processing method, suggested previously.  Luckily in our case, it wasn't a requirement that the report actually be printed to hard-copy.  So rather than try to send the report to a printer, you can run it to a file (ASCII, PDF, etc).

The batch server can process these, but since you'll need to specify a place to save the file, watch out for the following:

Be sure to use a UNC file path the path you wish to save to, otherwise you may get the following error: "Target file must be in UNC format."

Also be sure the necessary permissions have been applied to allow writing to that location, otherwise you'd get an error such as: "Unable to open file "

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! This will work, but doesn't truly fix the problem.

Comment: You're welcome.  This is another workaround, but may be helpful as well.  You may have already found that running the report to Print Archive suffers the same problem as printing directly to the printer.  But if you modify \Classes\RunbaseReportStd.runsImpresonated() to treat PrintMedium::PrintArchive the same as PrintMedium::File and PrintMedium::Mail, batches will run for it successfully and can be viewed/printed later from Basic > Inquiries > Print Archive

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the batches are trying to process server code, and the reports are meant to run client side.  Try the work around at this URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2009/06/16/how-to-run-client-batches-on-ax-2009.aspx

The gist is this, you create a batch group called "Client" or whatever, assign it to a batch server, then you run the **legacy** batch processor on the group.  This might work for you.

Comment: Is there something like this for AX 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the report to run on the server. 
You'll need to check the menu item and make sure it's set to run on server.
It's a property on the menu item.

When you add a report to the batch, take a look at the batch inquiry screen.
Select the batch job - then click 'tasks'. If the task shows 'Run Location' = client, it won't run in the server-based batch framework.

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error. I restarted AOS and SQL reporting service and it worked all fine. Hope this helps.